# Execute SQL code as one statement

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I'm interested how I can execute this SQL code as one statement in SQL Developer?

```
INSERT INTO "ADMIN"."AGENT" (ID, NAME, SERIAL_NUMBER, STATUS) VALUES ('22', 'agent', 'aawd', 'Active');

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


BEGIN

FOR loop_counter IN 1..1000
LOOP
INSERT INTO AGENT_HISTORY (EVENT_ID, AGENTID, EVENT_DATE) VALUES (loop_counter, 22, SYSDATE);
END LOOP;

COMMIT;
END;

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

BEGIN

FOR loop_counter IN 1..1000
LOOP
INSERT INTO CPU_HISTORY (CPU_HISTORY_ID, EVENT_ID, CPU_NAME, CPU_VALUE) VALUES (loop_counter, loop_counter, 'cpu1', dbms_random.value(1,100));
END LOOP;

COMMIT;
END;
```

I get error

```
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 13, column 1:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "BEGIN" 
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Answer (score 1):

Until it's only DML or queries, just wrap everything in `BEGIN ... END;`. Then it executes as one statement.